# How to prevent Cards from losing its dimensions when adding a larger text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this issue with some Cards and the CSS I think:

Look in the attached picture, I have 6 cards (could be more) and I want these cards keep its width and height dimensions no matter the text length. But unfortunately I'm not being able to achieve it. In the picture below, you can see how the first three cards have different heights

btw, is there any chance that this cards be displayed by inline-block? and if its possible, how could it be?

[image]

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 114em;
  grid-gap: 6rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(30rem, 1fr));
  align-items: start;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 3rem 6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.grid-item:hover {
  transform: translateY(-0.5%);
  box-shadow: 0 4rem 8rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card-img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card-content {
  padding: 3rem;
}

.card-header {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.card-text {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  line-height: 1.7;
  color: #3d3d3d;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.card-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3363ff;
  background-color: #d8e0fd;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}

.card-btn span {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.card-btn:hover,
.card-btn:active {
  background-color: #c2cffc;
}

.card-btn:hover span,
.card-btn:active span {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 60em) {
  body {
    padding: 3rem;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-gap: 3rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="./img/rome.jpg" alt="Rome" />
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-header">Rome</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          Rome is known for its stunning <strong> architecture</strong>, with the Colleseum, Pantheon, and Trevi Fountain as the main attractions. Rome is known for its stunning <strong> architecture</strong>, with the Colleseum, Pantheon, and Trevi Fountain
          as the main attractions.
        </p>
        <button class="card-btn">Visit <span>&rarr;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="./img/grand-canyon.jpg" alt="Grand Canyon" />
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-header">Grand Canyon</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          One of the world's natural wonders, the iconic Grand Canyon draws oohs and aahs from visitors perched at the edge of its
          <strong>towering cliffs</strong>.
        </p>
        <button class="card-btn">Visit <span>&rarr;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="./img/maldives.jpg" alt="Maldives" />
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-header">Maldives</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          The Maldives are known for their
          <strong>natural environment</strong> including the blue ocean, white beaches, and clean air, attracting tourists.
        </p>
        <button class="card-btn">Visit <span>&rarr;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="./img/maldives.jpg" alt="Maldives" />
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-header">Maldives</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          The Maldives are known for their
          <strong>natural environment</strong> including the blue ocean, white beaches, and clean air, attracting tourists.
        </p>
        <button class="card-btn">Visit <span>&rarr;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="./img/grand-canyon.jpg" alt="Grand Canyon" />
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-header">Grand Canyon</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          One of the world's natural wonders, the iconic Grand Canyon draws oohs and aahs from visitors perched at the edge of its
          <strong>towering cliffs</strong>.
        </p>
        <button class="card-btn">Visit <span>&rarr;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img" src="./img/rome.jpg" alt="Rome" />
      <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-header">Rome</h1>
        <p class="card-text">
          Rome is known for its stunning <strong> architecture</strong>, with the Colleseum, Pantheon, and Trevi Fountain as the main attractions.
        </p>
        <button class="card-btn">Visit <span>&rarr;</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Flexbox, I think you want something like this.

`margin-top` pushes the button at the bottom of the div.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  --margin: 5px;
  --padding: 5px;
  --border-size: 1px;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 2 * var(--margin) - 2 * var(--padding) - 2 * var(--border-size));
  margin: var(--margin);
  padding: var(--padding);
  border: var(--border-size) solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et risus eget quam volutpat interdum sit amet sed eros. Integer porta sem a quam maximus, eu dapibus est ultrices. Quisque ac nibh nibh. In ipsum nulla, finibus a consequat sed, porta
      rhoncus purus.</p>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et risus eget quam volutpat interdum sit amet sed eros. Integer porta sem a quam maximus, eu dapibus est ultrices.</p>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et risus eget quam volutpat interdum sit amet sed eros.</p>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300" alt="">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et risus eget quam volutpat interdum sit amet sed eros.</p>
    <button>button</button>
  </div>

</div>
```